# Completely disable mousewheel on a WinForm

Tags: c#, events, mouseevent

I have to completely disable the mouse wheel on a windows form and on every control contained in it, I've tried with the event mouse wheel but it doesn't work correctly:

```
    this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Form_MouseWheel);

    private void Form_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
    }
```

How can i completely disable mouse wheel on a windows form and in each control inside it?